# ImportError: cannot import name 'LazyLoader' from 'keras.utils.generic_utils' during ImageAI video object detection

Tags: python, keras

Code:

```
from imageai.Detection import VideoObjectDetection
import os

execution_path = os.getcwd()

detector = VideoObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
detector.loadModel()

video_path = detector.detectObjectsFromVideo(input_file_path=os.path.join(execution_path, "testvideo.mp4"),
                            output_file_path=os.path.join(execution_path, "traffic_detected")
                            , frames_per_second=20, log_progress=True)

print(video_path)
```

Result:
ImportError: cannot import name 'LazyLoader' from 'keras.utils.generic_utils'